# Apache 2.4 remoteip configuration for Amazon ELB

Tags: apache, amazon-elb

We are running Apache web servers on AWS EC2 instances behind Amazon ELB.

I wanted to configure remoteip which is available on Apache 2.4 and higher. As I understand, for this I need to enable remoteip and modify my /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/remoteip.conf file like this:

```
RemoteIPHeader X-Forwarded-For 
RemoteIPInternalProxy <ip-address>
```

Here, what should I use in place of ip-address as I am using Amazon ELB (since ELB gives me domain-name not IP address)?

Comment: What happenned when you used the supplied domain name?

Comment: It's showing same dynamic IP address of ELB.

Comment: What happenned when you used the supplied domain name?

Comment: Nothing changed, it's showing same dynamic IP address from ELB when I gave domain name.

Comment: You edited /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/remoteip.conf and typed in the supplied domain then saved the file and restarted the service. This did not solve the problem, so you went back and looked at the file, it had reverted to the IP address and nothing had changed? Clearly something did change.

Comment: I made the changes in remoteip.conf and restarted the apache, then I checked the new logs but it showed me the ELB IP address. I am able to see client IP address if I replace %h to %{X-Forwarded-For}i, but it's not recommended method to do.
I'm not sure what to right in remoteip.conf file as it has two header's type.